# Getting basic profile information of some one using graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am new to graph api.

i have done slight reading and found that we need access tokens for accessing a profile, but for my application i only have access to the email-id of a person

I just wanted to know if i can get anyone's basic profile information by just knowing thier E-mail id.

help in anyway way would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, without authorization you can´t get any user info, and you can´t search for Facebook users by email. You would have to authorize users with the email permissions and compare it that way.